# When to use absolute path?

Tags: programming-practices, path

I had given an answer on SO, [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149649/relative-path-in-python-few-folders-up/32149687#comment52189084_32149687) was concerning a problem with a relative path.  My answer was to use an absolute path, which I thought seemed simpler.  The asker claimed to need a relative path, but I couldn't tell why.

It seems reasonable that if you know to go to `../../../foo/bar/`, then you would also know to go to `/home/willie/foo/bar/`.

I can't think of a situation which requires relative paths except in a build script.  Are there others I'm not thinking of?  Is it bad practice to use one or the other in any situation?

Sorry if this question is off topic, all my googling yielded was *how* to use them rather than *why*.

Comment: Any time that you don't know ahead of time where the root folder will be residing.  There are many such scenarios besides build scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't think of a situation which requires relative paths

A possible reason to use *relative* path would be to use paths related to the location of the executable (and not to the current work directory); e.g. if your executable sits in `/home/will/bin/foo` you would use `/home/will/bin/../data/resource` (which is `/home/will/data/resource`) for some resource files. See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/294201/40065) for details.

Then, you could ship a file tree (e.g. a `.tar` archive) containing the executable (with some relative paths like `bin/foo` for the executable and `data/resource` for resources used by it), your user would install it at any place he likes (e.g. under `/home/will/`, or `/home/joe/soft/` or `/opt/` ...) and be able to run the executables and access resources.

This practice is not very common (IIRC, `xemacs` used it), because most systems have *conventions* about files, like the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) & [hier(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) and software gets installed (e.g. by some `make install` step) there.

Comment: The practice is still common. Any time you use hardcoded paths you can't place the file where it suits you. There are many legit reasons the (many different) conventions won't always suit everyone.

Comment: Even with filesystem standards, there are still multiple choices for base installation location, e.g. /usr, /usr/local, /opt/...

Comment: @Jules: but for a given software (and configured build tree), it is quite likely that it should be installed at some well defined (and single) place.

Comment: In an ideal world, the choice of which location to install in should be left to the local administrator. While this can be done (at least for open source software) by build-time configuration, I believe using paths relative to the binary location is generally a more friendly solution, and is probably the only completely flexible solution for non-oss applications.